# How do I get openfl running in the ios simulator

Tags: ios, haxe, openfl

I have the latest version of Haxe 3 installed along with the latest version of Xcode and OpenFL.

I'm inside my OpenFl project in the terminal and I run the following command:

```
openfl test ios -simulator
```

I get the following error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make
Haxe device build: Release-iphoneos-v7
haxe Build.hxml -D HXCPP_ARMV7 -cpp build/Release-iphoneos-v7
cd build/Release-iphoneos-v7; export HXCPP_NO_COLOR=1; haxelib run hxcpp Build.xml -Dios -Diphone -DHXCPP_ARMV7 -DHXCPP_CPP11  -DHXCPP_CLANG -DOBJC_ARC `cat Options.txt | while read LINE; do printf " -D$LINE"; done`
Error: Could not find build target "by"
make: *** [build-haxe-armv7] Error 1
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's choking on the word "by", which would be from the "Generated by Haxe" inserted at the top of generated C++ source files.

So try `haxelib run openfl build ios -simulator -Dsource-header=haxe` (or the `hxcpp` equivalent) to replace the default header with "haxe", it should work without the spaces in the header line.

Check this OpenFL issue, seems like the same problem: https://github.com/openfl/openfl/issues/1132

Afterward you might hit this issue too: https://github.com/openfl/openfl/issues/1153

Comment: The second link you suggested that I look at, issue 1153 was super helpful. Hope they get a real solution in place soon.